# How to change link in Django admin backend "Webseite anzeigen"

Tags: django, django-admin

I am developing a Django app and using both the admin backend and the developed website, which I refer to as the frontend, for the user. In the admin backend, there is a button "Webseite anzeigen" (Django German version) located at the top right corner. The code for this button is provided by Django. This button leads to the website or the frontend. I want to modify this button but I am not sure where to find it. For example, I want to increase the font size and change the color.

Answer (score 2):

I have referred [here](https://realpython.com/customize-django-admin-python/#overriding-django-admin-templates) and found the templates for Django-admin. They are located in your virtual environment--or wherever django is installed--not among your project files. For me, they were located in:

> venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/

The button you are referring is located in base.html

```
<a href="{{ site_url }}">{% translate 'View site' %}</a> /
```